# Stop Grails from HTML encoding messages?

Tags: grails

Note: in the process of upgrading from Grails 1.3.6 to 2.2.2.

If I have a tag such as:

```
<g:message code="some.code.here" args="${[someHTML]}" />
```

It is encoding the value as HTML even though the following is set in Config.groovy:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "none"
```

This was not a problem in Grails 1.3.6. It does it for all tags throughout the entire project. This is necessary to pass in the links this way, as we are passing in links based on the language.

Any idea why this is not working even though it was working before the upgrade, or a workaround?

If the HTML is in the .properties file, that renders fine. If the variable is just embedded into the page, it works fine. It the act of passing it in as an argument to g:message that causes it to error. I have attempted to use the <%=someHTML%> way to pass it in, but it doesn't seem to like that, telling me that I am missing a quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g:message was changed because of a XSS vulnerability (GRAILS-7170). See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10099 for a workaround for continuing to use HTML arguments in certain cases (such as your use case).

Comment: Side note: as of 2.3, you can use encodeAs="None" without the workaround.

Comment: -1 because the link containing the solution is now broken. The answer should include the most relevant part of the solution for this very reason